# Saved location of Imported mysql all DB Dump

Tags: mysql

I am trying to Import AllDb dump from command line using the command:

```
mysql -u root -p < C:\alldb.sql
```

`alldb.sql` is the dump file I want to import in my local machine.

But I am unable to get where these dump file will be stored.

Comment: "where these dump file will be stored" - do you mean "where the content of this dump file will be stored"?

Answer (score 0):

Open this file in text editor

There you will (hopefully) see database and table creation statements; (CREATE DATABASE ... CREATE TABLE ... or USE DatabaseName; CREATE TABLE... )
So, your dump will be stored in a new (or existing, depends on contents of your file) database.

for mysql data (i.e. raw db files): google://mysql windows data directory
(depends on your windows & mysql versions)

Comment: wish you luck in your quest to knowledge, @user3655257 :3